# How to send create an object in a form, ordering from another form in C#?

Tags: c#, forms

Dear genius developers, 
I'm developing a program with couple of forms in C#. I need to create a picture box in a form named as "Sub_Winding1" while I am in another form by pushing a button there.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
            PictureBox CopyPic1 = new PictureBox()
            {
                Name = PicBox_Name,
                Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\C#\...\Image\textura.jpg"),
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
            };
            CopyPic1.Location = new Point(X_Location, Y_Location);
            CopyPic1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(X_Size, Y_Size);
            CopyPic1.BackColor = PictureBox_Color;
            Sub_Winding1 ThisForm = new Sub_Winding1();
            ThisForm.Controls.Add(CopyPic1);
```

I would be appreciate you if you could find a solution. thanks.

Comment: It looks like you didn't show the form. Try `ThisForm.Show()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not opening the 2nd form anywhere, You should call **[`Show()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx)** inorder to Display the control to the user.just try this code,

```
Sub_Winding1 ThisForm = new Sub_Winding1();
ThisForm.Controls.Add(CopyPic1);
ThisForm.Show();
```

Comment: but I don't want to show the form, actually, the destination form is in a panel inside another main form. after this code, I am closing the current form and the destination form will be shown, but there is no picturebox there!

Comment: without showing the form how can you display the controls inside?

Comment: you want to have it on the same form?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I'd say the problem is this line:

```
Sub_Winding1 ThisForm = new Sub_Winding1();
```

This creates a new instance of Sub_Winding1.  But you say you already have an instance, somewhere, that is already getting shown via some other means.

You need to get a reference to that form instead of creating a new one, e.g.

```
Sub_Winding1 ThisForm = GetFormFromSomeWhere();  //Up to you to write GetFormFromSomewhere
```

Might look like this, if you have it embedded with the same name:

```
Sub_Winding1 ThisForm = SomeOtherForm.Sub_Winding1;
```

You might have to make the subform public.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but honestly I didn't understand it!